# PHP use array values to match to keys of another array then extract values into new array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$encoding = [0 => 'X', 1 => 'K', 2 => 'L', 3 => 'R', 4 => 'B'];

$digits = [1, 1, 4, 2];

// result should then equal ['K', 'K', 'B', 'L']
```

I can easily do this with a foreach loop and push into a new array.

```
$encoding = [0 => 'X', 1 => 'K', 2 => 'L', 3 => 'R', 4 => 'B'];
$digits = [1, 1, 4, 2];
$result = [];

foreach($digits as $digit) {
    $result[] = $encoding[$digit];
}
```

But I can't find if there is a function inbuilt into php to handle this OR a library of helper functions that can do this?

I also want it to be able to do the inverse and decode the value back to its digits.

Comment: Maybe `array_intersect()` ?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work because the keys have duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use `array_map`:

```
$encoded = array_map(function ($v) use ($encoding) { return $encoding[$v]; }, $value);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => K [1] => K [2] => B [3] => L )
```

To decode the result, you can use `array_map` again, this time using `array_search` to find the appropriate key value to return:

```
$decoded = array_map(function ($v) use ($encoding) { return array_search($v, $encoding);}, $encoded);
```

Or as suggested by @Barmar which is probably more efficient:

```
$encoding_f = array_flip($encoding);
$decoded = array_map(function ($v) use ($encoding_f) { return $encoding_f[$v];}, $encoded);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 4 [3] => 2 )
```

Comment: How would you also do the inverse of this to decode the value?

Comment: @robertmylne Use `array_flip()` to invert the encoding array.

Comment: Don't call `array_flip` in the callback function, do it once before mapping.

Comment: @Barmar done. I wanted to keep it a one-liner but that is clearly better.